# Python: write data to CSV from UDP

Tags: python, csv, udp

I used a socket library to receive data from UDP.

Data which I send have 32bit width (4 Bytes),

**My code:**

```
with open(csvf, 'w', newline='', encoding='ascii') as csv_handle:

    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_handle, delimiter=',')

    while(True):
        try:
            data,addr = s.recvfrom(buf)
            csv_writer.writerow(data) 
        except (socket.timeout,KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            raise
        except Exception:
            traceback.print_exc()
```

But in CSV file it presents 8 bit data.

For example:

I receive this UDP data in Wireshark:

[image]

**Desired CSV file output:**

4,4,8,12,16, etc.

**Actual CSV file output:**

0,0,0,4,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,8

32bit Unsigned Int, from memory (on FPGA) I read u32 value, these values create buffer, which I send via lwIP stack

```
u32 data;
...
data = XIo_In32(XPAR_AXI_BRAM_CTRL_0_S_AXI_BASEADDR+ptr);
```

now, I see a second problem, there is also problem with litte/big endian, in Python I will need byteswap operation too

Comment: 1 byte 8 bit, 32 bit value `XXXX`, why read hex value as string ? 4 mean `0x0004` on 32bit presentation. `struct.unpack()` will not help you, because `which data is incoming?`(32 bit : Real,Signed,Unsigned number). **wellcome to protocol world !**

Comment: 32 bit Unsigned Int

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
from binascii import hexlify
def hex_to_val(msg,ndx=0):
    """ msg = All or part of the packet.
        ndx = tuple or integer
              Tuple(start,end)
              Integer is only starting index
        Output is LIST
              """
    tmp = ""
    if type(ndx) == tuple : tmp = hexlify(msg[ndx[0]:ndx[1]])
    else: tmp = hexlify(msg[ndx:])
    return [int(tmp[i*4:(i*4)+4],16)for i in range(len(tmp)/4)]

print hex_to_val("\x00\x05\x00\x05\x00\x05\x00\x05",(0,-2))

>>> 
[5, 5, 5]
>>>
```